# The best way of spawning different types of animals?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a base class called `Animal` and some sub-classes that inherit from it. For example, classes `Cow` , `Pig`, `Chicken` etc.

Now I would love to spawn an animal in my world (game object). Should I create a spawn method for each sub-class, or just 1 method in my base class `Animal`. If I make a method in `Animal`, what would be the best way to reference my animals. Should I use prefabs?

How could I create a `Spawn(some parameter here)` method in `Animal` that could spawn `Pig` for example?

Comment: i would make a factory class that knows of every animal and can instantiate it. i would definitely use prefabs. take a look at http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/type-object.html and https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/MichaelHaney/20120412/168450/Game_Programming_Design_Patterns__The_Factory_Pattern.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use method to handle create animal object, I would use factory pattern to handler your Animal create thing.

create an `enum`  `AnimalType` be your method parameter, it can split let user decide which animal is user want.

```
public enum AnimalType { PIG, Cow, Chicken }
public abstract class Animal { }
public class Pig : Animal { }
public class Cow : Animal { }
public class Chicken : Animal { }
```

There is a `Dictionary<AnimalType, Animal>` to register `AnimalType` mapper with `Animal` object.

```
public class AnimalFacotry 
{
    Dictionary<AnimalType, Animal> _dict;
    public AnimalFactory() 
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<AnimalType, Animal>();
        _dict.Add(AnimalType.PIG, new Pig());
        _dict.Add(AnimalType.Chicken, new Chicken());
        _dict.Add(AnimalType.Cow, new Cow());
    }
    public Animal Spawn(AnimalType type)
    {
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(type))
            return _dict[type];
        return null;
    }
}
```

When you use this factory, you only pass the `enum` in `Spawn` type which animal you want to get.

```
var factory = new AnimalFacotry();
Animal cow  = factory.Spawn(AnimalType.Cow);
```

If the future you will add more `Animal`  class you just register the new animal in the `enum` and `Dictionary`.

factory pattern to deal with the problem of creating objects without having to specify the exact class of the object that will be created, because all animals inherit from `Animal` class.

Comment: If you had `Dictionary<AnimalType, Func<Animal>>` I'd say this was the winning idea.

Comment: `AnimalType.PIG, new Cow()`? I think you've got a typo or two there. ;)

Comment: You also had a typo in `Factory`. Also, why is `PIG` the only one in caps? You should make it normally cased like all the others.

Comment: @Enigmativity I am curious. Could you explain why would you use `Func<Animal>` instead of `Animal` be the value? or provide some reference link. I want to know thanks:)

Comment: @D-Shih - A factory is something that creates things. What you have designed is a repository which stores things. A `Dictionary<AnimalType, Animal>` can only store existing instances. If it were `Dictionary<AnimalType, Func<Animal>>` then you have a structure that will create animals and then it would be a factory.

Answer (score -1):

The idea here is setting an Export variable which could be an Array of GameObjects which might be the prefab of every kind of animal.
Then you can choose do it randomly (Generating a number between 0 and the length of the array) or choosing one position of the array.
Then you only have to choose where. If its the same empty object as spawn point, you only have to:
`Instantiate(theArray[position],transform.position,transform.rotation)`
Glad if I it's useful to you